# H2 schema still generated when spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3 with an H2 in memory database for testing. When I run my tests, the schema gets generated even when I specify the following property.

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

It seems that because Spring Boot defaults the following property when using H2

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

That this takes precedence over `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false`

Is this a bug?

Comment: No because both are different properties. Set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property to `none` then it should take precedence.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you *not* want the schema to be generated for an in-memory database?

Comment: @crizzis Well I was having errors with the auto generation so I needed to turn it off while I figured it out and worked on other things

Comment: @crizzis a scenario is when already exists either the `schema.sql` or `schema-h2.sql` files. Therefore the schema already exists.

Comment: @M.Deinum even when `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` as **none** works as expected - Why is available the `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` property if  the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property handles the same approach to reach the same goal?- is not clear when is mandatory use `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` over `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`

Comment: `generate-ddl` is only `true` and `false` which works with any provider. Whereas `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` allows you to specify the specify hibernate mode.

Comment: @ManuelJordan you do realize that the question asked was about an **in-memory** database?

Comment: @crizzis - Yes, but it could be applied to in a disk database as MySQL for _pre-production_ profile ... it to test with the target DB

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the reply, yes the former is generic and the latter has more options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is described in the Spring Boot Reference Documentation at the [Creating and Dropping JPA Databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.jpa-and-spring-data.creating-and-dropping) section as follows:

> By default, the DDL execution (or validation) is deferred until the
> `ApplicationContext` has started. There is also a
> `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` flag, but it is not used if Hibernate
> auto-configuration is active, because the `ddl-auto` settings are more
> fine-grained.

Since the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property is set by default when Hibernate is used, therefore the `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` property is ignored, at least with a H2 in-memory database